# Why do CSV::HeaderConverters stop processing when a non-String is returned?

Tags: ruby, csv

Why does processing of [header converters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) stop with the first non-`String` that's returned from a header converter?

### Details

After the built-in `:symbol` header converter is triggered, no other converters will be processed. It seems that processing of header converters **stops** with the first converter that returns anything that's not a `String` (i.e. same behavior if you write a custom header converter that returns a `Fixnum`, or anything else).

---

**This code works as expected**, throwing the exception in `:throw_an_exception`

```
require 'csv'

CSV::HeaderConverters[:throw_an_exception] = lambda do |header|
  raise 'Exception triggered.'
end

csv_str = "Numbers\n" +
          "1\n" +
          "4\n" +
          "7"

puts CSV.parse(
  csv_str,
  {
    headers: true,
    header_converters: [
      :throw_an_exception,
      :symbol
    ]
  }
)
```

---

However, if you switch the order of the header converters so that the `:symbol` converter comes first, the `:throw_an_exception` lambda is never called.

```
...

header_converters: [
  :symbol,
  :throw_an_exception
]

...
```

Comment: Any answer that's not from @JEG2 is likely to be pure speculation.

Comment: @FrederickCheung The question is stated as “Why does processing of header converters stop with the first non-String that's returned from a header converter?”—The answer on that is “because the code does explicitly break converters chain iteration on first non-String.” The clarification on “why is that done that way,” coming not from the author, is to be pure speculation, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I reached out to [JEG2](https://twitter.com/JEG2).

I was thinking that converters were intended to be a series of steps in a chain, where all elements were supposed to go through **every** step. In fact, that's not the way to best use the CSV library, especially if you have a very large amount of data.

The way it should be used (and this is the answer to the "why" question **and** the explanation for why this is better for performance) is to have the converters work like a series of matchers, where the first matched converter returns a non-`String`, which indicates to the CSV library that the current value has been converted successfully. When you do that, the parser can stop as soon as it's a non-`String`, and move on to the next header/cell value.

In this way you remove a TON of overhead when parsing CSV data. The larger the file you're processing, the more overhead you eliminate.

Here is the email response I got back:

> ...
>
> The converters are basically a pipeline of conversions to try. Let's say you're using two converters, one for dates and one for numbers. Without a linked line, we would try both for every field. However, we know a couple of things:
>
> - An unconverterd CSV field is a `String`, because that's how we read it in
> - A field that is now a non-`String`, has been converted, so we can stop searching for a converter that matches.
>
> Given that, the optimization helps our example skip checking the number converter if we already have a `Date` object.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

For unknown reason [`CSV#convert_fields`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/32674b167bddc0d737c38f84722986b0f228b44b/lib/csv.rb#L2213) function has a hilarious

[`break unless field.is_a? String  # short-circuit pipeline for speed`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/32674b167bddc0d737c38f84722986b0f228b44b/lib/csv.rb#L2226)

line in `converters.each`. I doubt I could suggest anything better than monkeypatching this function, but the cause is clear now.

Comment: if you look a few lines higher this behaviour is noted and is apparently mainly for reasons of speed

Comment: @FrederickCheung I did. This is in fact a perfect example of premature optimization. Header converters are by no means a bottleneck in CSV processing, and this `break` is both misleading and harmful.

Comment: the same code is reused for the fields though and it could conceivably be a bottleneck there.

Comment: I would either make this function to receive a third parameter `break_on_string`, defaulted to `true`, or at least bypass this `break` for `headers` (this is already passed as a parameter.) “Slow” is always better than “unexpected.”

Comment: @mudasobwa - that commit is a typo correction. When I check the history it seems that the `break unless ...` line originated in the re-implementation of CSV when @jeg2 replaced the old CSV implementation with the one based on FasterCSV. I may need to reach out to @jeg2 and ask him.

Comment: Actually, this goes waaaay back. On 2006-01-01, @jeg2 migrated (from rubyforge?), and [the line in question](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/blob/d9a7c49fb05a74922afcd5664f09b70d6a153cbe/lib/faster_csv.rb#L560) was already part of the library.

Comment: I sent an email via @jeg2's website.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a good idea so far; maybe `pull request` would do even better.